# Predictors of different size for time series prediction using LSTM with Keras

Tags: time-series, keras, lstm

I would like to predict time series values `X` using another time series `Y` and the past value of `X`.In detail, I would like to predict X at time t (`Xt`) using (`Xt-p`,...,`Xt-1`) and (`Yt-p`,...,`Yt-1`,`Yt`) with p the dimension of the "look back". 
So, my problem is that I do not have the same length for my 2 predictors.
Let's use a exemple to be clearer.

If I use a timestep of 2, I would have for one observation :
`[(Xt-p,Yt-p),...,(Xt-1,Yt-1),(??,Yt)]` as input and `Xt` as output. I do not know what to use instead of the `??`

I understand that mathematically speaking I need to have the same length for my predictors, so I am looking for a value to replace the missing value.

I really do not know if there is a good solution here and if I could to something so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers !

PS : you could see my problem as if I wanted to predict the number of ice cream sell one day in advance in a city using the forcast of weather for the next day. `X` would be the number of ice cream and `Y` could be the temperature.

Comment: as for your PS, why don't you just define Y as the temperature for the next day?

Comment: Yes, of course I could do that. But if I wanted to predict multi step head (for example 2), I would have `[(Xt-p,Yt-p+1,Yt-p+2),...,(Xt-2,Yt-1,Yt),(Xt-1,Yt,Yt+1)]`. So between timesteps, I would have same features feed in the network and I have the feeling that it could not be the optimal way for the learning. But I will definitely try this option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. do the following:

```
input_x = Input(shape=input_shape_x)
input_y = Input(shape=input_shape_y)
lstm_for_x = LSTM(50, return_sequences=False)(input_x)
lstm_for_y = LSTM(50, return_sequences=False)(input_y)
merged = merge([lstm_for_x, lstm_for_y], mode="concat") # for keras < 2.0
merged = Concatenate([lstm_for_x, lstm_for_y])
output = Dense(1)(merged)

model = Model([x_input, y_input], output)
model.compile(..)
model.fit([X, Y], X_next)
```

Where `X` is an array of sequences, `X_forward` is `X` `p`-steps ahead and `Y` is an array of sequences of `Ys`.

Comment: I am relatively new to LSTM and Keras so I do not really get what you mean. I understand that you create a net with 3 LSTM layers and it has 2 outputs.Then you train the net so that you can predic X_forward using X as input and predict Y using X. Is that right ? I would like to predict X_forward using X and Y, so shouldn't be something like X and Y as input and X_forward as output ?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like more to what I was expecting ! I will try this net